# What is the standard term for a USB flash-drive/pen/thumb/stick?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

There are several questions, particularly on Super User, which refer to the use of these drives but there isn't a standard term in use nor a standard tag. Though SU has 'thumb drive', it is not consistently used.

Would there be any advantage to having a standard tag to ease searches?

Taking the initial responses into account the preferred terms (in order of usefulness) seem to be

- [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive)
- [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage)
- [pendrive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pendrive)
- [thumbdrive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thumbdrive)
- [usb-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive)
- [usb-stick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-stick)

Comment: The correct term is flash drive, however many people insist on calling them by names with varying degrees of nonsense. I am also noticing the spread of this issue based on the fact that you didn't even include that in your question...

Comment: I always carry a 360kb 5 1/4 inch floppy in my pocket. I don't need your young kid's toys.

Comment: @Ian Elliott - whilst flash drive is correct it has perhaps become somewhat ambiguous with the advent of 'SSDs' as the difference can be in form factor rather than mechanism.

Comment: Should this be tagged `[retag-request]`?

Comment: You forgot **finger**.

Comment: technically SD cards and others are also flash memory so unfortunately 'flash drive' cannot be right although it would be elegant.  also 'usb-storage' or 'usb-drive' can't be right because there are hard disks, card readers, cd/dvd drives etc that connect with USB.  I vote for 'usb-stick'.

Comment: Our software  supports two dozen (and counting) languages and runs on machines sitting in a factory. A user plugs in their USB flash drive and saves a report or backs up settings. We use the highly generic term `USB` because translation issues with `flash` and `stick` are fraught with complications! No-one complains because in our context the meaning of `USB` is unambiguous.

Answer (score 17):

I'd go with [usb-flash-drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive). On Wikipedia, all of the terms you suggested redirect there.

Comment: +1 I agree, `stick/thumb/pen/finger` are too specific and just `drive` could refer to an external hard drive which has it's own tag.

Comment: `Flash drive` or `USB flash drive` are probably best but it is context-dependant. You may need to consider translation into dozens of languages (if you write software or user manuals) when an imprecise term like `USB` may be acceptable, provided it is unambiguous in the context used.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipeida redirects all to "[USB flash drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive)"

[USB stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=usb%20stick&redirect=no)
[Thumb drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=thumb_drive&redirect=no)
[Pen drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pen_drive&redirect=no)

I think we should use that. It's the most descriptive and least ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for `usb-storage` - this doesn't differentiate between pen drives and USB hard drives, admittedly. Sometimes that's a good thing, sometimes it's not. (Things like plugging your phone into your computer are a third category, I guess...)

Answer (score 2):

Thumb drive is always the one that sticks in my mind because it is what I use personally, but I think what Jon said concerning usb-storage is probably the best because it is more generic and can encompass all the others which seem to be describing the style more than the function.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it depends on the place of the world you are in. Down here in Argentina, only the most technical people will refer to them as anything other than "pendrives", and only when talking online. Pendrive has become as something of a standard here.

Comment: them **as** anything **other** than

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "USB-storage" sounds right... yet I do think that it definitely should have both "USB" and 'storage".

Hows "USB Storage Device"?

And for USB external HDDs, hows "USB Mass Storage Device"?

Answer (score 0):

As per the recommendations, I believe we should use [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive) as the global term.  Currently, there are a *lot* more questions just tagged [flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-drive), most of which deal specifically with a USB flash-drive.

---

I have begun to re-tag some of these questions as usb-flash-drive (instead of just flash-drive).  Originally, I just wanted to make flash-drive a synonym of usb-flash-drive, but wanted people's opinion on *if* that should even be made a synonym first.  I mean, flash-drive *could* refer to solid-state drives, but that is rarely (if at all) what users use the tag for.  Going through some, I have seen cases where people put flash drive instead of [ssd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssd), but have been changing them to SSD so far.

Thoughts?

Comment: It'd probably be better to write a new Q with a retag request on that. I don't see anything wrong with mass-retagging those, *if* there is no ambiguity within `[flash-drive]`.

Comment: If you deal with the dozen or so cases where it's a mess/unclear, a mod can merge the rest