# Please clean up the USB drive tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I'm currently updating the Tag wiki for [usb](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb) and found some irregularities:

- [usb-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) x153 – the most commonly used one, also mentions in the excerpt: "especially devices known otherwise as flash drive, USB stick, USB key and thumb"
- [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage) x20 – with no tag wiki (excerpt)
- [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive) x113 – with no tag wiki (excerpt)
- [flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-drive) x350 – "A flash drive is a storage device that consists of flash memory with an integrated USB interface"
- [usb-stick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-stick) x6 – with no tag wiki (excerpt)

In [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/339/what-is-the-standard-term-for-a-usb-flash-drive-pen-thumb-stick) we seemed to agree that [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive) is the best tag for USB sticks / pen drives.

Therefore:

- Merge [usb-stick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-stick) → [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive).
- Merge [flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-drive) → [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive) (or the other way round?)
- Merge [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage) → [usb-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive).

Comment: i'd add the [flash-drive] tag to the list tho, it does have a wiki exerpt

Comment: Updated my question, makes more sense now I guess @jou

Comment: good find, this needs some merge lovin' for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Merge [usb-stick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-stick) → [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive).
> - Merge [flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-drive) → [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive) (or the other
>     way round?)
> - Merge [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage) → [usb-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive)

Since  [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage) has bulk quantity of questions & is more generic, I opted for the other way around. Also, [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage) includes non-flash drives, so it was not mapped as a synonym to [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive)

Comment: *Does* make sense, cheers.

Comment: *just* updated my post. @slhck

Comment: Fixing the descriptions now.

Answer (score 3):

i'd add the [flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-drive) tag to the list of things meaning the same as usb stick

I think [usb-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) and [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage) are synonymous and include external HDDs -any mass storage device connecting over USB would count .

[usb-stick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-stick) , [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive) and [flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-drive) mean usb flash drives only