# Duplicate tags for "USB stick" never closed

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-request

This question is still in action:

[What is the standard term for a USB flash-drive/pen/thumb/stick?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/339/what-is-the-standard-term-for-a-usb-flash-drive-pen-thumb-stick)

...

I have found 4 usb drive tags:

- [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive)
- [usb-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive)
- [usb-stick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-stick)
- [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage)

Perhaps there should only be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive) and [usb-stick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-stick) are identical and synonymized. Same goes for [usb-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) and [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage).